# aws ecs console running task with error "unable to run task", how to debug/find the real error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to run a new ECS task on a new cluster using Fargate as the deployment.  I'm doing everything via the aws console.  However when I go to run my task I simply get the error in a red banner
"**Unable to run task**",
nothing else.  I've tried looking for the service events described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-event-messages.html#service-event-messages-1
but can't find them.  Does anyone know how to debug this?

Comment: If there are EC2 instances registered within the ECS cluster and if you ran a service, try logging into the registered instance and doing a `docker ps -a` and checking `docker logs` on the stopped containers if any.

Comment: unfortunately no registered instances

Comment: yea, I'm not sure if you can run tasks/containers without a registered host/instance @J.Hammond

Comment: Sorry I should also specify that i'm using Fargate here.  My understanding is that I don't have any kind of dedicated ec2 instance for this?

Comment: yes please do edit the question with the said detail. @J.Hammond

Comment: Sorry i've updated the question,  Additionally I believe now that the larger issue is the IAM user i'm using doesn't have the right permissions, because another user with greater access was able to run the task without error.  However I still have not been able to answer the question on how one could use the provided error to determine this.

Comment: @J.Hammond I think you are in the right direction. From my experience, when things are not wokring on AWS without observable information, the first thing to check is IAM permission. When developing something on AWS, I always set the permission to maximum (resources *, actions *) during development. Only until  I am done with functional testing, I start to restrict down the IAM permission.

Answer (score 1):

You can show the stopped tasks where you can see the reason for stopping the container. Also on the details of the particular task you can find the logs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).